# What is the fastest java collection for retrieving large numbers of DTOs?

Tags: java, performance, collections

I'm returning large numbers of collections from a DTO object and was wondering if anyone could point me in right direction.  Any type of collection will do, but I don't know which one is best suited for the task of returning a large number of objects.

I know this can change based on threading and the like, but I'm at least looking for general guidance and benchmarks.  Also, I'm required to stay within standard Java collections (no third-party libraries).

Comment: yes.  All DTOs will be unique.

Comment: take a look at this http://aaronz-sakai.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/java-collection-performance.html

Comment: LinkedHashSet => fast insertion but increasing memory for storing elements' pointer. But if that doesn't impact significantly your memory, you can choose for it.

Comment: Pick your collection based on how you intend to use it, not perceived performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As irreputable says: If you need a simple collection, than ArrayList should perform good because it is based on an Array which is fast by definition using the System functions.

If you set the initial capacity to a higher value (don't know what you call a large number), than it will be even faster because it reduces the amount of incremental reallocation.

Any other collection has some kind of an overhead like looking for hashcodes or beeing synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` initialized at the correct size (if you know how many DTOs you'll be adding, or an upper bound) is the simplest and smallest `Collection` you'll find. By setting its size at initialization, it won't need to resize its internal array, an operation which produces garbage. It's better that directly using an array, which is really low level, and which you'd need to manage manually if it needs resizing (that's what the `ArrayList` does for you).

To create a pre-sized `ArrayList`, use the `ArrayList(int capacity)` constructor.